# Realm Migration Issue in Android

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

I have a DB which contains few new columns added. As per my understanding, When someone creates the App for the first time, the default schema version set to 0. Later which we need to increment.

What I have done is, I have set the SCHEMA_VERSION = 1 as there is a new change in the schema and expecting the freshly installed app on any device will contain the default schema as 1.

I am testing with two different devices, one is running Android 6.0 (Marshmellow) another one is Android 8.0 (Oreo).

Problem is , when running the app in 6.0, I get the default schema is set as -1 for the first time. Later when I set explicitly Schema Version 1, it sets the default as 1 which is as expected and not calling the Migration as it is installed on the 
 device for the first time.

```
RealmConfiguration.Builder builder = new RealmConfiguration.Builder();
    builder.schemaVersion(SCHEMA_VERSION); // SCHEMA_VERSION = 1
    builder.migration(new Migration());

Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(builder.build());
Realm.getDefaultInstance().close();
```

But when I am trying the same code in 8.0, I am getting default schema is set as 0 and when I am setting

```
builder.schemaVersion(SCHEMA_VERSION); // SCHEMA_VERSION = 1
```

,the Migration() is getting called and throwing Field already exists as it is considering **SCHEMA_VERSION = 1** is the update.

Which means, in 8.0 even if we install the app for the first time, it is taking care that **SCHEMA_VERSION = 0** is the default one with all of columns added (Because I can see the db already got the columns added).

> What could be wrong? Why there are two different Default Schema
>   versions (-1 & 0) on fresh App in two devices? And in any case if it
>   is installed on a device for the first time, why would the migration
>   get called?

This is the code snippet which I am using before setting the **SCHEMA_VERSION** 
to get the Default Schema Versions..

```
DynamicRealm dynamicRealm = DynamicRealm.getInstance(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration());
long version = dynamicRealm.getVersion();
dynamicRealm.close();
```

I also have searched SO Q&As, read articles but could not find anything matches my problem. Kindly track the issue [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6076). Would be very grateful if someone could explain what went wrong and how to fix.. Thanks. :)

Comment: Did you followed the doc: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations

Comment: Migration sample app for you ref : https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/migrationExample

Comment: I don't know your migration code nor what "fails" so I can't really say anything

Comment: @Arvind, yes I am following the docs also I have checked the github code as well. The problem is the different behavior on different devices. One is calling the Migration and another one is not.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, It is not about Migration code works or fails. The question is why is it calling the Migration at the first place and in other device it is not ?

If you check the code snippet I added to get the Default schema in the later part of my question, you will see, if I execute these 3 lines of code before RealmBuilder, I am getting two different default schema versions in two different devices. OS 6.0, OS 8.0 behaves differently. Kindly help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out, the device Samsung Note 8, started working after restarting the device. Before that, I tried to uninstall and re-install back the application and I am pretty sure I removed everything possible. Which did not work and started calling the Migration. Now this is not occurring anymore and works perfectly. :)